# Adding Values to a Spreadsheet Based on the Values of Another Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks; "Master" and "zControl". They each have a worksheet called "Master" and "zControl", respectively.

I need to add a string to Column "N" of "Master" if a specific phrase is found in both Column "A" of "zControl" and Column "M" of "Master".

Column "M" of "Master" will likely contain much more information than just the phrase in Column "A" of "zControl", so it will not be an exact match, but will contain the value of Column "A" in "zControl" in sequential order with spaces separating the words.

The string to be added to Column "N" of "Master" needs to be pulled from the cell in Column "B" of "zControl" that is in the same row as the matching value  found in Column "A" of "zControl".

Example of what I need in plain language:

If "A2" of "zControl" matches part of "M44" of "Master", then add "B2" of "zControl" to "N44" of "Master".

Find the next match and perform the same logic...

Another example of what I need the macro to do in plain language:

If "A49" of "zControl" matches part of "M2" of "Master", then add "B49" of "zControl" to "N2" of "Master".

Find the next match and perform the same logic...

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Adder()

Dim WS_Master As Worksheet 
Dim WS_Control As Worksheet 

Dim WS_Master_Lastrow As Long
Dim WS_Control_Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

Set WS_Master = Workbooks("Master").Worksheets("Master")
Set WS_Control = Workbooks("zControl").Worksheets("zControl")

'Find last row of WS_Master
WS_Master_Lastrow = WS_Master.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, 
xlPrevious).Row

'find last column of WS_Master
WS_Master_Lastcol = WS_Master.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, 
xlPrevious).Column

'Find last row of WS_Control
WS_Control_Lastrow = WS_Control.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, 
xlPrevious).Row

'Add control sheet data to a array
Dim ControlData() As String

ReDim ControlData(1 To WS_Control_Lastrow, 1 To 3)

For i = 1 To WS_Control_Lastrow
ControlData(i, 1) = Trim(WS_Control.Range("A" & i).Value)
ControlData(i, 2) = Trim(WS_Master.Range("M" & i).Value)
ControlData(i, 3) = Trim(WS_Control.Range("B" & i).Value)
Next i

'Loop through Master sheet
For i = 1 To WS_Master_Lastrow
'Loop through Control sheet
For j = 2 To WS_Control_Lastrow
    'if both string found
    If InStr(1, WS_Control.Range("A" & i).Value, ControlData(j, 1), 
vbTextCompare) > 0 And _
    InStr(1, WS_Master.Range("M" & i).Value, ControlData(j, 2), 
vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'Add Save Value to the row
        For k = 1 To WS_Master_Lastrow
            If WS_Master.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                WS_Master.Range("N" & j).Value = WS_Control.Cells(i, 2)
            End If
        Next k
        Exit For
    End If
Next j
Next i

MsgBox "Completed!", vbInformation, ""

End Sub
```

At this point, I am getting hung up in the IF Statement.  I am nearly certain the cause of the error is the ".Range" parameter, but cannot figure out how to fix it so the macro adds the necessary value to the correct cell in Column "N".

This is easily the most complicated thing I have done in VBA, and the first time I have worked with an array.  The reason I mention this is that, even without the error, I may not be doing what I want to do.

Any thoughts or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and, if able, provide your input.

EDIT:

Here is where I am now.

```
Sub Adder()

Dim WS_Master As Worksheet 'This was GNC
Dim WS_Control As Worksheet 'This was the ControlSheet.

Dim WS_Master_Lastrow As Long
Dim WS_Control_Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

Set WS_Master = Workbooks("Master").Worksheets("Master")
Set WS_Control = Workbooks("zControl").Worksheets("zControl")

'Find last row of WS_Master
WS_Master_Lastrow = WS_Master.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, 
xlPrevious).Row

'find last column of WS_Master
WS_Master_Lastcol = WS_Master.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, 
xlPrevious).Column

'Find last row of WS_Control
WS_Control_Lastrow = WS_Control.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, 
xlPrevious).Row

'Add control sheet data to a array
Dim ControlData() As String

ReDim ControlData(1 To WS_Control_Lastrow, 1 To 3)

For i = 1 To WS_Control_Lastrow
ControlData(i, 1) = Trim(WS_Control.Range("A" & i).Value)
ControlData(i, 2) = Trim(WS_Master.Range("M" & i).Value)
ControlData(i, 3) = Trim(WS_Control.Range("B" & i).Value)
Next i

'Loop through data sheet
For i = 1 To WS_Master_Lastrow
'Loop through control sheet
For j = 2 To WS_Control_Lastrow
    'if both string found
    If InStr(1, WS_Control.Range("A" & i).Value, ControlData(j, 1), 
vbTextCompare) > 0 And _
    InStr(1, WS_Master.Range("M" & i).Value, ControlData(j, 2), 
vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'Add Save Value to the row
        WS_Master.Range("N" & j).Value = WS_Control.Cells(i, 2)


    End If
Next j
Next i

MsgBox "Completed!", vbInformation, ""

End Sub
```

All this is doing is adding the value of "B2" from "zControl" to "N2" of "Master", "B3" of "zControl" to "N3" of "Master" and so on...

Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  As implied earlier, I'm pretty new to VBA and am learning as I go.

Comment: Try Range("N"& j).value=cells(j,3)

Comment: @Sivaprasath After making the change, I got "Run time error '1004':" "Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error" in the previous line (the start of the IF statement).

Comment: Why are you looping in K through columns? <If WS_Master.Cells(i, k).Value <> "" Then> Cells (Row Index,Column index). If your row count have crossed the maximum number of columns it will throw an error

Comment: @Sivaprasath Great catch!  I changed the IF statement to: If WS_Master.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then WS_Master.Range("N" & j).Value = WS_Control.Cells(i, 2) End If   .  Now it will run through, but puts the information from "B1" of "zControl" in "N1" of "Master" and "B2" of "zControl" in "N2" of "Master" and so on...  This is not right, "B1" is a header and "B2" should not correspond with "N2".  Any other thoguhts?

Comment: Please update the new code to the Question. also Loop from 2 so that you leave out the header

Comment: @SivaprasathV The code has been updated and the loop for the control sheet had been changed to start at "2".  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Why do you need the for Loop with k...it does not do anything....also    <If WS_Master.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then> this if statement doesnt make sense....use without the if and for loop

Comment: @SivaprasathV Thanks again.  I did what you said and made the changes in the question above.  The output is as stated in the third from last sentence in the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub adder()
dim zcontrol as worksheet
dim wsmaster as worksheet

application.screenupdating=false
application.displayalerts=false

On error goto Reset_settings

Set wsmaster = Workbooks("Master").Worksheets("Master")
Set zcontrol = Workbooks("zControl").Worksheets("zControl")

zcontrol_lr=zcontrol.range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row
wsmaster_lr=wsmaster.range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row
wsmaster_lc=wsmaster.cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft).column

For i=2 to wsmaster_lr
    for j=2 to zcontrol_lr
        if instr(1,Trim(wsmaster.range("M" & i).value), trim(zcontrol.range("A"& j).value),vbBinaryCompare) > 0 then
            wsmaster.range("N"& i).value=zcontrol.cells(j,2).value
        end if
    next j
next i

Msgbox "Completed!",vbinfomration,""


reset_settings:
application.screenupdating=true
application.displayalerts=true


end sub
```

I think this would help you...I havent tested the code. try it out.

Comment: Hmm.  This still isn't working, but I believe it is _nearly_ working.  The first time I ran it, it ran through without any errors, but didn't place add any values to "N" either.  The second time I ran it, I changed the value of "M2" in "Master" to equal the value of "A3" of "zControl" and the value of "B3" in "zControl" was added to "N2" of "Master".  It is doing a _direct_ comparison rather than a _partial_ comparison.  I'm wondering if I need a "Like" operator after going through some searches...Not sure, VERY late here (almost 5 AM), I need sleep.  TY for all your help with this so far!!!

Comment: I figured it out.  The string and substring needed to be switched in the instr statement.  Once that is done, the program works great.  Thank again for all your help!  Once you update the answer, I will mark it as "Accepted".